# Need a EF/Linq/MVC library to encapsulate/abstract the filesystem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Our system accepts uploaded files. They are stored in the filesystem, and paths are kept in an Entity Framework `File` entity. It works, but isn't transparent/simple, and there are lots of "moving parts" to be maintained.

The idea of using a high-level tool like EF means I don't have to worry about mundane db stuff. I'd like the same sort of thing but for managing a repository of filesystem objects.

*Is there a library which can manage the filesystem for me?* With these sort of features:

```
- storing files
- moving
- deleting
- detecting missing or corrupted files
- computing+comparing hashes
- working with image files
- extracting metadata
- determining paths; relative to webserver, absolute, etc.
- updating files
- referencing all this via a linq-like syntax
- hopefully integrated with EF
- etc.
```

Comment: I'm using MVC4, EF5 SQL Server Express LocalDb 2012, Win/NTFS

Comment: We solved that by not using the filesystem at all, but instead save all the files uploaded by users into the db itself in binary compressed format. We limited the maximum file size to 5mb, though.

Comment: @HighCore: yes we used to do that too, and it was really easy and simple to maintain, but it didn't scale well, and caused headaches when doing backups, and our files are often PDFs which can be large.

Comment: You are looking for DMS - document management system or perhaps NoSql document database. Your current tool set is wrong. With relational DB like SQL Server you can also use Filestream type to handle blobs stored on file system.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Please post comment as answer so I can mark correct.

Comment: That is not an answer to your particular problem. It just points to another direction. When you choose a solution for your problem, write it here as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bobby B,

try http://sensenet.codeplex.com/ it's an open source asp.net DMS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a full-blown alternative to Sharepoint. I need something 10^10 simpler :)